# Swift - Still printing "Optional" even after checking if object exists - how do I unwrap

Tags: swift, object, option-type, userdefaults

Very new to Swift so a very simple problem here but I am struggling to unwrap an optional from a `UserDefaults` stored value. The value for UID is "dan". Here's the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let uidObject1 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UID")   

    if let uid = uidObject1 {
          updateUsername.setTitle("\(uid)", for: UIControlState.normal)
          print("on load \(uid)")
    }
}
```

This changes the button updateUsername label and also prints to the console the following...

> on load Optional("dan")

I cannot get rid of Optional().  I've tried to unwrap uid.

> print("on load (uid!)")

as Xcode tells me I cannot force unwrap value of a non-optional type 'Any'.

From searching around I understood that checking - `if let uid = uidObject1` - removed the Optional() as it only runs if `uidObject1` exists. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: 
Here is my set code;

```
@IBAction func updateUsername(_ sender: AnyObject) {                         
   if let uid = userName.text {                        
      UserDefaults.standard.set("\(userName.text)", forKey: "UID")                  
      updateUsername.setTitle("\(uid)", for: UIControlState.normal)                
   }        
}
```

> ANSWER - Needed to unwrap the set (userName.text) like so > (userName.text!)  SOLVED. Thanks Oliver.

Comment: That probably means that you previously set the default for "UID" to the string `Optional("dan")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you set UID to UserDefaults you set the string using the same method you have used to print. However if you don't unwrap the optional at that point then the string is saved as "optional(Dan)". So you are unwrapping in the code above correctly but the string is already "optional(Dan)".

Eg your code to set the value of UID likely looks like this

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue("\(name)", forKey: "UID")
```

But name is an optional. Unwrap name and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I unwrapped the set userName.text like this - UserDefaults.standard.set("\(userName.text!)", forKey: "UID") - and it now its not coming back as an optional, it was indeed being set as an optional. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem! glad I could help :)

Comment: Do not use `setValue` unless you know and need the KVC functionality.

Comment: It wasn't a suggestion, just an example of what I meant.

Comment: Then make an example using the right thing and remove `Value`, `set(...` infers the String type.

Answer (score -1):

`object(forKey:)` returns a value of type `Any?`. When assigning UID you should be casting it to the type you want like this:

```
guard let uidObject1 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "UID") as? String else { return }
```

or using the `string(forKey:)` method like

```
guard let uidObject1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UID") else { return }
```